# Operations on multiple columns accross many tables

Tags: r, multiple-columns, frame

I have two tables (dt1, dt2). dt2 contains the same variables names as dt1.
For each variable in dt1 I would like to multiply it with its values from dt2.
In the exemple below, x from dt1 will get multiplied with 4 and y with 7.
How would be the fast way to do it?
Thank you

```
  set.seed(123)
  dt1 <- data.frame(x = sample(1:10, 10, TRUE), y = sample(1:10, 10, TRUE) )
  dt1
  dt2 = data.frame (names = c("x", "y"), values = c(4, 7))
  dt2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`purrr` style

```
map2_df(dt1, dt2 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = names, values_from = values), ~.y * .x)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
       x     y
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1    12    35
 2    12    21
 3    40    63
 4     8    63
 5    24    63
 6    20    21
 7    16    56
 8    24    70
 9    36    49
10    40    70
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `sweep`

```
> sweep(dt1, 2, dt2$values[match(dt2$names, names(dt1))], "*")
    x  y
1  12 35
2  12 21
3  40 63
4   8 63
5  24 63
6  20 21
7  16 56
8  24 70
9  36 49
10 40 70
```

or

```
> dt1[] <- t(t(dt1) * dt2$values[match(dt2$names, names(dt1))])

> dt1
    x  y
1  12 35
2  12 21
3  40 63
4   8 63
5  24 63
6  20 21
7  16 56
8  24 70
9  36 49
10 40 70
```